# Is there a way to turn off the sound response when pressing a button for the entire flutter application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I'm trying to disable all sounds when clicking on any of the possible buttons (ElevatedButton, TextButton, IconButton etc.).
But no matter how much I try, I can't do it by using the app theme or any other way.

I've already tried setting `enableFeedback = false` for all button types, but it absolutely doesn't work for IconButton.

So, I can't do it for whole app and the only solution is to set `enableFeedback = false` for each button, but isn't there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a little research, I discovered that you can set the value `enableFeedback = false/true` in the theme for any buttons that inherit `ButtonStyleButton`, but you cannot set this value for `IconButton`, since it inherits `StatelessWidget` and does not request data from the application theme.

In case if you need to set `enableFeedback` value for your `IconButton` widgets, you need to do it separately for each `IconButton` (doesn't matter whether you do this using other widgets or whether you actually set each value manually).

I think the issue can be closed, but it really looks like bug.

Answer (score 0):

Set the enableFeedback in your theme, not for every button.

For example:

```
elevatedButtonTheme: const ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
      enableFeedback: false,
    )),
```

should disable the sound for all ElevatedButtons. If you have any other type of buttons, you will need to apply a theme again for this button (OutlinedButton for example).

Comment: I've already tried setting `enableFeedback = false` for all button types in theme, but it absolutely doesn't work for IconButton.
I'll add to the question, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up your button in a GestureDetector and implement the code in the onTap there and leave the button onPressed empty.
Maybe if this works for you, you can create a new Widget that wraps the following code that you can utilise more than once.

```
    GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // Your button's functionality
  },
  child: OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {}, // Leave this empty
    child: Text('Button Text'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. Gesture detector does not cover the area where the button is pressed and in this case the sound will not disappear and the action will not be launched. You can set `onPressed: null`, but in this case many buttons will change their style.